# Issue using Coldfusion FileExists when checking files with UTF-8 and ASCII

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, coldfusion, file-exists

When trying to detect the existence of the files that were encoded in UTF-8 with FileExists function, the files could not be found.

I found that in the Coldfusion server the *Java File Encoding* was originally set to "UTF-8".  For some unknown reason it was back to default "ASCII". I suspect that this is the issue.

For example, a user uploaded a photo named 云拼花.jpg while the server Java file encoding was set to UTF-8, and now with the server Java file encoding set to ASCII, I use

```
<cfif FileExists("#currentpath##pic#")>
```

The result will be not found i.e. file does not exist.  However if I simply display it using:

```
<IMG SRC="/images/#pic#">
```

The image will display.  This caused issues when I try to test the existence of the images. The images are there but can't be found by FileExists.

Now the directory has a mix of files encoded in either UTF-8 or ASCII.  Is there anyway to:

1. force any upload file to UTF-8 encoding
2. check for the existence of the file

regardless of CF Admin Java File Encoding setting?

Comment: Maybe you're just missing a `/` in `#currentpath#/#pic#`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the slash / is already part of the variable #currentpath#

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your page.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
```

This should fix the issue.